# Get div's separated by <td> to get table behaviour

Tags: css, css-tables, tablerow

I have a unique code structure like this one : http://jsfiddle.net/VqzeQ/ .
What I want to achieve is the output like this one :

[image: output]

My question is, is it possible to achieve output like the image above with only CSS? I've played with `display:table`, table-cell etc, with no luck.

If it's impossible to do with only CSS, what would you suggest me to achieve that out put with the code structure given?

Comment: Why can't you change the HTML?

Comment: I can't, it's part of a complex application

Comment: IMO, if the application is strongly attached to HTML, the design is bad.

Comment: I don't think it can be done, particularly with the variable height. Bite the bullet and change the HTML to something sensible.

Comment: @dreamexploded: You need to tweak the markup for pure css tables. See my answer given below.

Comment: @VladislavQulin You should have 1 billion upticks for that comment `for(var i=0; i<1000000000; i++) upTickComment('Vladislav Qulin');`

Comment: You are hosed unless you can AT LEAST use javascript to dynamically calculate the div heights ... tables autosize and the sizing is different per browser per version. GL =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**AS OP STATED:**

> My question is, is it possible to achieve output like the image above with only css? I've played with display:table, table-cell etc, with no luck.

**Yes it is possible,** but you need to tweak the markup for pure css tables like given below;

**HTML:**

```
<div class="table-row">
    <div class="number table-cell">1</div>
    <div class="content table-cell">
        1111 11111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 11 11 1111111 111111111111111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 111 11 11 1111111 1111111111 11 11 1 11111 1 111111 1
    </div>
</div>

<div class="table-row">
    <div class="number table-cell">2</div>
    <div class="content table-cell">
        222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222 222 22222 222         
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.number, .content {border:1px solid #333;}
.table-row { display: table-row; }
.table-cell { display: table-cell }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/ZrxHZ/)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @A.K . Yes this something that I will do if there's no  possible "css only" solution :) I come in the middle of production process so changing the code structure is the last option I have to do because it will have big impacts to other part of application.

Comment: @dreamexploded : If you got the solution, then accept the answer.

Comment: I don't think IE7 supports `table-cell` or `table-row`. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way you can do what you want only with css. You can try js, like this:

```
var numbers = $(".number");
var contents = $(".content");
for (var i = 0, l = numbers.length; i < l; i++)
  $(numbers[i]).height($(contents[i]).height());
```

But this is bad desicion also.

Answer (score 0):

What are you doing...? We have tables for a reason. Use it to its fullest extent, not half way.

To answer your question: no, can't do that with CSS. You're trying to set the height of one div based on the height of another and the only relation between them is that they're both the n-th children of two elements. The best you can do is give them both a fixed height as shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VqzeQ/1/). You can't get the height of one and set the others to that with just CSS.

I could write out a JS explanation, but I won't, because you should be using tables to properly display tabular data.

Comment: I can't do that, the height is need to be auto. I understand the weak of the code sructure, but I come in the middle of production process so changing the code structure is the last option I have to do because it will have big impacts to other part of application.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind all of the rows being the same height you could do this in your css:

```
.number, .content {border:1px solid #333;}
.number {float: left; position: relative; right: -8px;}
.content, .number {height: 55px;}
```

Note: this works in jsFiddle. I haven't checked it in a browser

Otherwise I think you are going to get into JavaScript fixes.